# Jquery On Paste Not Working For Validating Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate one form field, as the user types so that a message will be displayed if a certain domain extension is typed in the e-mail address.

Keeping the example simple so if the user types the letter 'j', it shows an alert, however if the user pastes the letter 'j', it does not.

I thought paste or propertychange would work but it is not working.  I have had a good search through SO and not found any suggestions that worked.

Does anyone kindly have a suggestion?

```
$("#signup-Email").on( "keyup input propertychange paste", function(event) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if(event.which == 74) 
         alert("Entered!");
   }, 50);
});
```

Comment: If you're going to be loose with indentation, please always put curly braces round if code blocks.

Comment: It's hard to read the code :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11605419/4248328   Or best would be:-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628244/4248328

Comment: how you are pasting ? cntrl+v or right click paste? when you do using cntrl+v you will get event.which is undefined. because of keyup event when you press cntrl key your keypup event will get fired. thats y you are not able to alert

Comment: Thanks to @AlivetoDie - I worked out the answer from your supplied link.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @AlivetoDie, for pointing me in the correct direction - the base for my answer was in

[jQuery function bind on 'input propertychange' not firing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327140/jquery-function-bind-on-input-propertychange-not-firing-as-expected/28628244#28628244).

The following code took care of my requirements:

```
var text = "j";
$("#signup-Email").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value === text) {
        alert ("don't even think about it");
    }
});
```

Comment: glad to help you:):)